# onclick dentro de append

Tags: javascript

Intento hacer un onclick en un anchor dentro de un append
y no sirve. ¿Como puedo resolver esto?

```js
$(function(){


        var weekday= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
        var months = ["January","February","March","April","May", "June", "July","August","September","October","November","December"];
        var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear();

        function days(month,year) {
          //last day of month
          var lastDay = new Date(year,month + 1, 0).getDate();

          //first day of month
          var a = new Date("1 ,"+months[month]+","+year+"");

          //month string
          $("#date").html(months[month]+" "+year);

          var counter = 0;
          $("#days").html("<tr>");
            for(var i = 1; i < lastDay+1;i++,counter++){

              //blank space
              if(i == 1){
                for(var j = 0; j < a.getDay();j++,counter++){
                  $("#days").append("<td></td>");
                }
              }

              //new week
              if(counter%7 == 0){
                $("#days").append("</tr><tr>");
              }

              //display days
              $("#days").append("<td class='day_active'><a href='' onclick='dayClicked("+i+")'>"+i+"</a></td>");

            }
        };

        //dayClicked
        function dayClicked(day){
          alert("you have clicked day: "+day);
        }


        //left click
        $("#prev").on("click",function(){
          if(month == 0){
            year--;
            month = 12;
          }
          month--;
          days(month,year);
        });

        //right click
        $("#next").on("click",function(){
          if(month == 11 ){
            year++;
            month = -1;
          }
          month++;
          days(month,year);
        });

        days(month,year);

      });
```

```css
.btn{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn" id="prev">&lang;</span>
<span id="date"></span>
<span class="btn" id="next">&rang;</span>
<table>
    <tr id="weekdays">
      <td>Su</td>
      <td>Mo</td>
      <td>Tu</td>
      <td>We</td>
      <td>Th</td>
      <td>Fr</td>
      <td>Sa</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="days"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

el codigo no funciona porque nunca se bindea el evento click para el anchor tag.

podes aprovechar el uso de jquery (ya que lo usas) haciendo uso del atributo data-* para asignarle el valor del dia y al hacer click sobre una clase definida en el anchor tomar el valor del atributo data-* para solucionar tu problema

```
$(function(){
    var weekday= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    var months = ["January","February","March","April","May", "June", "July","August","September","October","November","December"];
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    function days(month,year) {
      //last day of month
      var lastDay = new Date(year,month + 1, 0).getDate();

      //first day of month
      var a = new Date("1 ,"+months[month]+","+year+"");

      //month string
      $("#date").html(months[month]+" "+year);

      var counter = 0;
      $("#days").html("<tr>");
        for(var i = 1; i < lastDay+1;i++,counter++){

          //blank space
          if(i == 1){
            for(var j = 0; j < a.getDay();j++,counter++){
              $("#days").append("<td></td>");
            }
          }

          //new week
          if(counter%7 == 0){
            $("#days").append("</tr><tr>");
          }

          //display days
          $("#days").append("<td class='day_active'><a class='day-click' data-day="+ i +" href='#'>"+i+"</a></td>");

        }
    };

            //left click
    $("#prev").on("click",function(){
      if(month == 0){
        year--;
        month = 12;
      }
      month--;
      days(month,year);
    });

    //right click
    $("#next").on("click",function(){
      if(month == 11 ){
        year++;
        month = -1;
      }
      month++;
      days(month,year);
    });

    days(month,year);

    //dayClicked
    $('.day-click').click(function(){
      var day = $(this).attr('data-day');
        alert("you have clicked day: "+ day);
    });

  });
```

el ejemplo funcionando [AQUÍ](https://jsfiddle.net/6hqqrsv1/)

Saludos

Comment: Otra pregunta. Si quiero pasar los parámetros month & year en la función dayClicked(). Para hacer esto: days(month,year); y que el calendario muestre el mes y año arriba sin que se regrese a su mes actual. ¿Como haría esto?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que al definir la función `dayClicked` adentro de `$(function(){})` esta solo puede usarse durante la ejecución de esta función, una vez terminada, `dayClicked` ya no está al alcance de los métodos `onclick` en tu HTML. Sólo debes de ponerla afuera de esta función, en un ámbito global y ya funcionará.

```js
$(function(){


        var weekday= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
        var months = ["January","February","March","April","May", "June", "July","August","September","October","November","December"];
        var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear();

        function days(month,year) {
          //last day of month
          var lastDay = new Date(year,month + 1, 0).getDate();

          //first day of month
          var a = new Date("1 ,"+months[month]+","+year+"");

          //month string
          $("#date").html(months[month]+" "+year);

          var counter = 0;
          $("#days").html("<tr>");
            for(var i = 1; i < lastDay+1;i++,counter++){

              //blank space
              if(i == 1){
                for(var j = 0; j < a.getDay();j++,counter++){
                  $("#days").append("<td></td>");
                }
              }

              //new week
              if(counter%7 == 0){
                $("#days").append("</tr><tr>");
              }

              //display days
              $("#days").append("<td class='day_active'><a href='' onclick='dayClicked("+i+")'>"+i+"</a></td>");

            }
        };

        //left click
        $("#prev").on("click",function(){
          if(month == 0){
            year--;
            month = 12;
          }
          month--;
          days(month,year);
        });

        //right click
        $("#next").on("click",function(){
          if(month == 11 ){
            year++;
            month = -1;
          }
          month++;
          days(month,year);
        });

        days(month,year);

      });
//dayClicked
function dayClicked(day){
  alert("you have clicked day: "+day);
}
```

```css
.btn{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn" id="prev">&lang;</span>
<span id="date"></span>
<span class="btn" id="next">&rang;</span>
<table>
    <tr id="weekdays">
      <td>Su</td>
      <td>Mo</td>
      <td>Tu</td>
      <td>We</td>
      <td>Th</td>
      <td>Fr</td>
      <td>Sa</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="days"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: esta respuesta no funciona, arroja el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Evita hacer un append con código html, es mejor crear los elementos por separado y así mejoraras el performance de tu script, admás podras manejar mejor los eventos, por ejemplo veamos la linea donde te falla el evento onclick

```
//display days
$("#days").append("<td class='day_active'><a href='' onclick='dayClicked("+i+")'>"+i+"</a></td>");
```

Deberías de crear el TD y el A por separado de la siguiente forma

```
var td;
var a;
//.....
function days(month,year) {
//....
td = $("<td>").addClass('day_active');

a = $("<a>").html(i).click( 
       //Mandas los parametros dentro de un objeto {param1:'valor' , param2:'valor'....}   
      { day:i }, 
      //Dentro de function los llamas como event.data.param1, event.data.param2, etc...
      function(event){ dayClicked(event.data.day); 
}); //fin del click
//Agregas el A dentro del TD
td.append(a);
//El TD se lo agregas a "#days" que debería ser un TR
$("#days").append(td);
//....
} // fin de days(month,year)

function dayClicked(day){ alert(day); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Tu problema esta en que la function `dayClicked` no se encuentra en el contexto global de la aplicación (`window`) sino en el contexto de la funcion que lo agrupa.

Entonces cuando haces click tienes el error `Uncaught ReferenceError: dayClicked is not defined`

**Solucion**

declara la funcion fuera de `$(funciont() { })`

O

declara una funcion anonima con referencia al contexto de window.

```
window.dayClicked = function(day)  {
    alert("you have clicked day: "+day);
}
```

```js
$(function(){


        var weekday= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
        var months = ["January","February","March","April","May", "June", "July","August","September","October","November","December"];
        var d = new Date();
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth();
        var year = d.getFullYear();

        function days(month,year) {
          //last day of month
          var lastDay = new Date(year,month + 1, 0).getDate();

          //first day of month
          var a = new Date("1 ,"+months[month]+","+year+"");

          //month string
          $("#date").html(months[month]+" "+year);

          var counter = 0;
          $("#days").html("<tr>");
            for(var i = 1; i < lastDay+1;i++,counter++){

              //blank space
              if(i == 1){
                for(var j = 0; j < a.getDay();j++,counter++){
                  $("#days").append("<td></td>");
                }
              }

              //new week
              if(counter%7 == 0){
                $("#days").append("</tr><tr>");
              }

              //display days
              $("#days").append("<td class='day_active'><a href='' onclick='dayClicked("+i+")'>"+i+"</a></td>");

            }
        };

        window.dayClicked = function(day)  {
            alert("you have clicked day: "+day);
        }

        //left click
        $("#prev").on("click",function(){
          if(month == 0){
            year--;
            month = 12;
          }
          month--;
          days(month,year);
        });

        //right click
        $("#next").on("click",function(){
          if(month == 11 ){
            year++;
            month = -1;
          }
          month++;
          days(month,year);
        });

        days(month,year);

      });
```

```css
.btn{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn" id="prev">&lang;</span>
<span id="date"></span>
<span class="btn" id="next">&rang;</span>
<table>
    <tr id="weekdays">
      <td>Su</td>
      <td>Mo</td>
      <td>Tu</td>
      <td>We</td>
      <td>Th</td>
      <td>Fr</td>
      <td>Sa</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="days"></tbody>
</table>
```